# Delphi 11 Code completion (ctrl + space) brings up list of templates rather than normal code completion window

Tags: templates, delphi, autocomplete, code-completion, delphi-11-alexandria

As the title suggests, when I try to use code completion manually via ctrl+space I get this:

[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

edit: More info. This is seemingly only in a particular project. I replicate this issue with say a string s and typing s.(ctrl+space). In a fresh delphi 11 vcl project the various code completion options you'd expect come up. However in this particular project, the template list comes up.

Comment: What have you typed in so far?

Comment: If your answer is "nothing", then this is normal behavior. At least type some letters in before or directly after you invoked code completion, so Delphi can start filtering the completion list!

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Code_Completion

Comment: This also happens to me every now and then, particularly in some units of mine. Since the units compile, it is hard not to consider this a bug in RAD Studio.

Comment: The templates are always included in the list unless filtered out based on what was already typed. Outside of code blocks / procedures / etc they are all that shows.  A parsing issue can exclude identifiers on occasion.

Comment: Not enough information. If you randomly invoke Ctrl+Space, it has no context as to what to display, so it displays everything. Impressive job of providing graphics while missing the most important information, which is where you invoked Ctrl+Space. This question should have been closed long ago, and (possibly) reopened when you provided the additional context.